# Issues with Web crawler, not sure how to solve this

Tags: python, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I'm creating a web crawler, and I am running into an issue. What my script does is crawl the first page for links, then crawls the links on the pages it finds. The issue I seem to be running into is after the first set of links are crawled it goes to crawl the links of the pages from the first crawl, however there seems to be an issue links that are using the TLD (http://example.com vs /about for example). I have tried breaking up those links and adding some more filtering to catch and record them, I've tried running my own commands to filter out the full URLS and nothing seems to make a difference. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code:

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# creating requests from user input
url = raw_input("Put in your domain! Without the 'http://www' part : ")

def makeRequest(url):
    print("Trying...", url)
    r = requests.get('http://' + url)
    # Adding in BS4 for finding a tags in HTML
    soup =  BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser') 
    # Writes a as the link found in the href
    output = soup.find_all('a')
    return output

def makeFilter(link):
    # Creating array for our links
    found_link = []
    for a in link:
        a = a.get('href')
        a_string = str(a)

        if not a_string:
            continue    
        # if statement to filter our links
        if a_string[0] == '/':
            # Realtive Links
            found_link.append(a_string)     

        if 'http://' + url in a_string:
            # Links from the same site
            found_link.append(a_string)

        if 'https://' + url in a_string:
            # Links from the same site with SSL
            found_link.append(a_string)

        if 'http://www.' + url in a_string:
            # Links from the same site
            found_link.append(a_string)

        if 'https://www.' + url in a_string:
            # Links from the same site with SSL
            found_link.append(a_string)

    output = found_link
    # print a_string

    return output   

# Function for removing duplicates
def remove_duplicates(values):
    output = []
    seen = set()
    for value in values:
        if value not in seen:
            output.append(value)
            seen.add(value)
    return output

# Makes the request -> Filters the links -> Removes duplicates
def createURLList(values):
    global filtered_list
    try:
        requests = makeRequest(values)
    except:
        print "Try again."
    try:
        new_list = makeFilter(requests)
    except:
        print "I can't make a list out of this."
    try:
        filtered_list = remove_duplicates(new_list)
    except:
        print "I can't do shit with this list."

    return filtered_list

result = createURLList(url)

# print result
crawled_urls = []
crawled_urls = open('crawled_urls.txt', 'w')

# for verifying and crawling resulting pages
for b in result:
    sub_directories = createURLList(url + b) # issue is right here, it's adding the url on the full URL in some instances

    # remove_duplicates(sub_directories)
    for z in sub_directories: # goes through the arrays crawled 
        crawler = []
        crawler.append(z)
        crawler = remove_duplicates(crawler) # remove duplicates from list
        crawler = str(crawler)
        crawled_urls.write(crawler + '\n')
crawled_urls.close()
```